# AnimTicksPerSecond GUID

Tags: c++, windows, animation, directx, guid

I'm trying to parse an .X file (for use in DirectX) for the fps of an animated mesh...the .X file uses template data. I would like to get the variable within the template: AnimTicksPerSecond, however, I cannot tell the parser to recognize this template because I don't have the GUID...is there a way of looking up the GUID? Here is my parser code, it works with standard templates but, AnimTicksPerSecond is not defined in the same file(provided by DirectX SDK).

```
BOOL cAnimationCollection::ParseObject(LPD3DXFILEDATA pDataObj, DWORD Depth, void **data)
{   
    if(pDataObj->IsReference())
        return true;

    if(CompareDataObjectType(pDataObj, TID_D3DRMAnimationSet)) //Animation Set is defined in rmxfguid.h(comes with DX SDK)
    {
        // Create and link Object
        cAnimationSet *AnimSet = new cAnimationSet();
        AnimSet->m_Next = m_AnimationSets;
        m_AnimationSets = AnimSet;

        // Increment # Animation Sets by 1
        m_NumAnimationSets++;

        // Set Animation Index to global count
        AnimSet->m_index = index;
        index++;

        LPD3DXFILEDATA pSubData;
        SIZE_T nChildren;

        if(!strcmp(GetObjectName(pDataObj), "Unknown") || !(AnimSet->m_Name = GetObjectName(pDataObj)))
            AnimSet->m_Name = _strdup("NewAnimationSet");
        if(SUCCEEDED(pDataObj->GetChildren(&nChildren)))
        for(SIZE_T index = 0; index < nChildren; index++)
            if(SUCCEEDED(pDataObj->GetChild(index, &pSubData))){
                ParseChildObjects(pSubData, Depth, data);
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first Google result for `AnimTicksPerSecond` is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172263.aspx), which has this declaration:

```
template AnimTicksPerSecond
{
    < 9E415A43-7BA6-4a73-8743-B73D47E88476 >
    DWORD AnimTicksPerSecond;
}
```

Looks like a GUID to me.

Comment: I'm looking for the IID, sorry

Comment: When I reference AnimTicksPerSecond in my code, I get an error stating that AnimTicksPerSecond is an "unreferenced variable". Somewhere in the system include files is a reference to the proper IID for AnimTicksPerSecond...for example...in rmxfguid.h, you can find a DEFINE_GUID macro for Animation templates which have the IID: TID_D3DRMAnimation. TnimTicksPerSecond is not on the list in rmxfguid.h...where is it? how do I reference it?

Comment: You're free to define it the same way the others are defined in *rmxfguid.h*. Use the `DEFINE_GUID` macro, make up an identifier (such as `TID_D3DRMAnimTicksPerSecond`), and put in the constituent numbers of the GUID shown above.